# why a runnable doesn't use the value it current runs

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I created a runnable in class `a` to call a static function in another class,'b', and use a static bool value to decide whether call the runnable again. It is a auto-throw-dice app and the run function in class 'a' will be called in mainactivity, and the functions in b class are about the processes of throwing dices(start, stop, restart).  Code of class a

```
private boolean endtag;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable rend = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        buttons.endbutton();
        endtag = buttons.turnend;
        Log.e("1", "round1");
    }
};//runnable for dices stopping and getting the value

final Runnable rcountinue = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        buttons.continuebutton();
        Log.e("2", "round1");
    }
};//runnable for throwing the dice again

final Runnable rrun=new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(rend);
        if(!buttons.turnend)
        {
            handler.postDelayed(rcountinue, 2000);
            handler.postDelayed(rrun,6000);
        }
    }
};

public void run() {
    delay = 0;
    buttons.startbutton();
    handler.postDelayed(rrun,4000);
}
```

code in class b(=button) is like:

```
public static boolean turnend;
public static void startbutton() {
    //code for dice running
    Log.e("button", "start");
}

public static void endbutton() {
    //code for stopping the dice running and check whether can stop throwing dices again
    if(some situations)
    {
       turnend=true;
       Log.e("button", "valuechange");
    }
    Log.e("button", "end");
}

public static void continuebutton() {
    //code for throwing dice again
    Log.e("button", "continue");
}
```

the quetion is, as I start the app, the runnable always runs one more time than I expect.As the log shows below. It should be stopped after valuechange but the rrun runs one more time. Why and how to solve it?

> 11-17 15:03:11.580: E/button(10851): start
>   11-17 15:03:15.600: E/button(10851): valuechange
>   11-17 15:03:15.600: E/button(10851): end
>   11-17 15:03:19.590: E/button(10851): continue
>   11-17 15:03:21.600: E/button(10851): end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is happening in your code.

1. `a.run()` calls `startbutton()`, which prints **`start`**. Then it posts `rrun` to be executed in 4000ms.
2. 4000ms later `rrun.run()` posts `rend` to execute immediately, checks for `!buttons.turnend` which is apparently `true`, so it posts `rcountinue` in 2000ms and `rrun` (that is itself) in 6000ms.
3. `rend.run()` calls `buttons.endbutton` which prints **`valuechange`** and **`end`**, and also sets `buttons.turnend` to `true`. Then it prints **`round1`** (not shown in your dump).
4. 2000ms later `rcountinue.run()` calls `buttons.continuebutton()` which prints **`continue`**. Then it prints **`round1`** (not shown in your dump).
5. 4000ms later `rrun.run()` again posts `rend` to execute immediately, checks for `!buttons.turnend`, but this time it's `false`, so it does nothing more.
6. `rend.run()` again calls `buttons.endbutton` which apparently follows an execution path which prints only **`end`** (a mismatching brace in your code indicates that you cut something from it)

It seems also that you changed timeouts in the code after copy-pasting the log dump, but this doesn't affect the overall flow.

Comment: got it, the reason that rrun runs again is in step 2 as you said, rrun will get the 'buttons.turnend' value before changing it. So how can I modify the code to make sure value changing before rrun get it?

Comment: @WenhuiHu I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Probably you should schedule `rrun` from `rend` and do it only in case you don't set the flag.

Comment: I've add some comment on the code. It is an auto-throw-dice  app with 3 dices and I hope that it can stop throwing again as they get some special type(like '4,5,6')

Comment: You are right, I solve it, maybe I need debug more times to make sure there will be no mistake. Thank you.